# Oracle SQL how to use between in string

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get range of result using between or any other operator?

Example:

`select * from sku between 'sku1' and 'sku5'`

**Input Data**

```
SKU4 
SKU5 
SKU10 
SKU11 
SKU12 
SKU1 
SKU2 
SKU3 
SKU150101 
SKU15010601 
SKU4 
SKU1 
SKU2 
SKU1 
SKU2 
SKU3 
SKU20164 
SKU20165 
SKU20166 
SKU20167 
SKU20168 
SKU20169
```

**Result expected:**

```
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
SKU4
SKU5
```

The `sku` is not fix to the format sku[1-...]. It also can be any other string that been set to it.

Comment: And what is wrong with your expression?  It seems to do what you want.

Comment: i got only sku1 and sku5

Comment: What is the actual data in your table?  Do `sku2`, `sku3` and `sku4` exist?

Comment: yes..sku2,sku3,sku4 all exist in the table

Comment: `between` works fine.  Here is an example:  http://rextester.com/NMQS79802.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  If you really do have a problem, then ask another question with more appropriate data and a better explanation.

Comment: here are the example data i got: SKU4
SKU5
SKU10
SKU11
SKU12
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
SKU150101
SKU15010601
SKU4
SKU1
SKU2
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
SKU20164
SKU20165
SKU20166
SKU20167
SKU20168
SKU20169..i want only sku1,sku2,sku3,sku4,sku5

Comment: The problem is that `sku` is a character column and the comparison is done based on ASCI values. So `sku2` is bigger then `sku100`

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name..do you have any answer how to get the expected result? tq..

Comment: Is your upper and lower range character string always of the same length? Otherweise, what is the expected result of `select * from sku between 'sku1' and 'sku20'`? And result of `select * from sku between 'sku1' and 'skv0'`?

Comment: Please append missed information in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your numbers are strings and the sort order for strings is different then those for numbers. If every sku starts with the string `sku` it would have been a better design to **not** store that prefix at all and store the SKU number as a proper `number` in the database.

---

You can use something like this:

```
select *
from the_table
where sku like 'sku%' -- only those that start with the prefix
  and to_number(regexp_replace(sku, '[^0-9]', '')) between 1 and 5
```

The `regexp_replace()` extracts only digits from the string, then converts that to a proper number which can be compared correctly using the `between` operator.

Comment: tq @a_horse_with_no_name ..but this code seems like i know what are the front of it..example if it start with 2017MM0001? the sku1-sku5 is simple example..it can be 2017MM0001-2017MM0005 or abcd12345abcd1-abcd12345abcd5 or abcd-abce..

Answer (score 0):

For string operation you want to use exact scenario with text case sensitive.
Can you try the below code

**Method 1:**

```
Select * from table_name where column_name like 'sku_'
```

**Method 2:**

```
Select * from table_name where column_name in ('sku1','sku2','sku3','sku4','sku5')
```

Comment: already try..still not get expected result..sku1sfsdfs, sku2sdfsdfs, sku3asdada, sku4dgdgd, sku5ffsfs still showing..

Comment: select substr(column_name, 1, 4) where lower(column_name) like 'sku%';

Comment: @eikaz code is updated. Check the updated code and let me know the result.

Comment: hi @sahathulla..if use like then all the string contains sku1 will appear right? hi g00dy.. i cannot use substr because the format for it does not fix to sku[1- ...]

Comment: @eikaz this code will show only sku[1-9]. if you have sku1 twice it shows both the code. if you have sku11saece it will not show.

Comment: tq @sahathulla..how to i get range result example sku1 to sku5 ignoring all the sku11saece,sku2343434 and so on..

Comment: @eikaz please check the above code. It ignoring all the sku11saece,sku2343434 and so on

Answer (score 0):

If the below sample is your data as you said earlier:
here are the example data i got: SKU4 SKU5 SKU10 SKU11 SKU12 SKU1 SKU2 SKU3 SKU150101 SKU15010601 SKU4 SKU1 SKU2 SKU1 SKU2 SKU3 SKU20164 SKU20165 SKU20166 SKU20167 SKU20168 SKU20169..i want only sku1,sku2,sku3,sku4,sku5

Then try below query:

```
select * 
from (
  Select * 
  from table_name 
  order by column_name aesc
) 
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

Comment: hi @Rajesh..i cannot only fetch 5 rows only because maybe there still a lot more rows to fetch..

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the numbers from the string and use it in the `BETWEEN` clause ? Considering it always starts with 3 letters :

Ex :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  TEXT VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(1, 'sku1');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(2, 'sku2');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(3, 'sku3');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(4, 'sku4');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(5, 'sku23');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(6, 'sku40');
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, TEXT) VALUES(7, 'sku123');
```

Then :

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TEXT, 4)) BETWEEN 3 AND 30;
```

Result :

```
|--------------|--------------|
|      ID      |     TEXT     |
|--------------|--------------|
|      3       |     sku3     |
|      4       |     sku4     |
|      5       |     sku23    |
|--------------|--------------|
```

Or of course if you need the strings in the `BETWEEN` clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TEXT, 4)) BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('sku3', 4)) AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('sku30', 4))
```

[Try the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61e4c/10).

**EDIT** :
According to the comment, if you need to get the last digits from the string, you can use the following (uses [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) function and a regexp to extract the digits from the end of the string) :

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT,'\d+$')) BETWEEN 3 AND 30;
```

`\d+` matches a group of digits.
`$` matches end of line.

[New fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fea20/2).

Comment: hi @yann39 ..if i know what are the character will start it will be simple.. but the parameter is dynamic...it can be 2017MM0001-2017MM0005 or abcd12345abcd1-abcd12345abcd5 or abcd-abce..

Comment: OK so does it concerns only the last digit characters from the string ? Then could you consider using a regexp to get them independently from the string ? See my edited answer.

Comment: TEST = table name, TEXT = column name?

Comment: Yes you have to replace with your own values :)